# Singleton being constructed twice

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class Logger : public std::ofstream
{
public:
    explicit Logger(std::string const& filename = "log.txt"):
        std::ofstream(filename.c_str())
    {
        assert(*this);

        *this << "-- log file start --\n" << std::endl;
    }

    Logger::~Logger()
    {
        *this << "\n-- log file end --" << std::endl;

        this->close();
        this->clear();
    }
};

Logger logger;

template<class T>
class NotCopyable
{
public:

    NotCopyable() { }
    ~NotCopyable() { }

private:

    NotCopyable(NotCopyable const&);
    NotCopyable const& operator=(NotCopyable const&);
};

template<class T>
class Singleton : public NotCopyable<Singleton<T> >
{
public:

    static T& GetInstance()
    {
        if (!instance)
        {
            logger << "Initialize Singleton" << std::endl;

            instance.reset(new T());
        }

        return *instance;
    }

protected:

    Singleton() { }
    virtual ~Singleton() { }

private:

    static std::unique_ptr<T> instance;
};

template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<T> Singleton<T>::instance;

class Factory : public Singleton<Factory>
{
public:

    Factory() { logger << "Factory constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~Factory() { logger << "Factory destructor" << std::endl; }

    void Blargl() { logger << "Blargl" << std::endl; }

};

bool DoStuff()
{
    Factory::GetInstance().Blargl();

    return true;
}

bool Thingy = DoStuff();

int main(int, char*[])
{
    logger << "Start main()" << std::endl;

    Factory::GetInstance().Blargl();

    logger << "End main()" << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
-- log file start --

Initialize Singleton
Factory constructor
Blargl
Start main()
Initialize Singleton
Factory constructor
Blargl
End main()
Factory destructor

-- log file end --
```

I feel stupid, but can't see why the factory is being constructed twice instead of once. What's going on here?

Comment: Reason #57 why Just Create One beats the hell out of Singleton.  If you simply used a global, you'd be done already.

Comment: I tried running your code, but didn't duplicate the problem.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 (Express Edition).

Comment: I'm on Redhat with G++ 4.8.1.

Comment: Is there perhaps an implicit equivalence between `!instance` and `instance != nullptr` being generated?

Comment: @abiessu: It should work. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool

Comment: @FredLarson: just looked up the spec on `str::unique_ptr` and found that my question is (or should be) moot for all implementations of C++11.

Comment: @cHao: If you used a global, you might well end up with a similar initialisation-order fiasco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to run your code, and had the same behaviour you described on OSX, Apple llvm 5.0.
It works fine if you define the static instance variable inside the GetInstance() method:

```
static T& GetInstance()
{
    static std::unique_ptr<T> instance
    if (!instance)
    {
        logger << "Initialize Singleton" << std::endl;

        instance.reset(new T());
    }

    return *instance;
}
```

I think that the problem you have in your code is the unspecified order of execution between the initialization of the Singleton::instance at its declaration point (default constructor), and the assignment in the GetInstance() method.
So, if what I am saying is right, the order of execution is probably something like:

1. `GetInstance()` call from `DoStuff()` call
2. Default-construction of the `Singleton<Factory>::instance`
3. new `GetInstance()` call inside `main()`

---

Edit: tested my theory with the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr()
    : p() {
        std::cout << "Initalizing Ptr" << std::endl;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<T> p;
};



template<class T>
class Singleton : public NotCopyable<Singleton<T>> {
public:
    static T& GetInstance()
    {
        if (!instance.p)
        {
            std::cout << "Initalizing Singleton" << std::endl;
            logger << "Initialize Singleton" << std::endl;
            instance.p.reset(new T());
        }
    return *instance.p;
}

protected:
    Singleton() { }
    virtual ~Singleton() { }

private:
    static Ptr<T> instance;
};

template<class T>
Ptr<T> Singleton<T>::instance;
```

Output:

1. Initalizing Singleton
2. Initalizing Ptr
3. Initalizing Singleton